# How to use Lynda.com in android development

Tags: android

my question is so simple:
I already have a lynda.com account, I got it to learn android development but since I started with the existing courses I am facing a problem which is I can't organize things, each course is from 1 hour to 3 hours maximum and they are not organized and not given difficulty level or so. It seems that each course speaks about one specified topic in android. so my question is if any one already have a lynda account and knows how things go in the site please tell me. the reason I want to complete android development learning at lynda in the very high quality the offer in the courses but I just don't know the path

Comment: what I need guys is something like list or road-map if available believe me if lynda have a road map for all of their topics with this incomparable quality, they will change the world of online education.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Lynda.com much, but what I used to learn Android development was Udemy. The courses there are very good quality and offer several resources including a Q&A. I can link you the course that I took, if you'd like.

Comment: I have a udemy account and I really have very long experience using it, it is awesome indeed but since instructors on udemy are kind of freelancers they are not profissional like lynda, again udemy in terms of variety are invincible and are in the top but some specific details can't be found easily in udemy. to understand my point clearer watch any video in any topic from lynda on youtube and you will realize the difference but their problem is that they are not organized well, many thanks for your answer :)